# Can anything in React Native by styled?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm wondering because I've added a component called 'progressCircle" and attempted to center it but no styling I apply seems to effect it.

I noticed there's an outerCircleStyle prop in the documentation does this mean I can't use standard styling?
https://github.com/MrToph/react-native-progress-circle

**Code (ProgressCircle is what I'm trying to center)**:

```
 <View>
    <StatusBarPlaceHolder style = {styles.bar}/>
       <ProgressCircle style = {{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}
          percent={30}
          radius={100}
          borderWidth={12}
          color="#3399FF"
          shadowColor="#999"
          bgColor="#fff"
      >
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{'30%'}</Text>
      </ProgressCircle>

      <Card style = {styles.card}>
        <Card.Content>
          <Title style = {styles.cardTitle}>{test.macro}</Title>
          <Text style= {styles.cardElements}>{test.title}</Text>
          <Progress.Bar progress={0.7} width={200} height={10} />
        </Card.Content>
        <Card.Actions>
        </Card.Actions>
      </Card>

      <Card style = {styles.card}>
        <Card.Content>
          <Title style = {styles.cardTitle}>{30}</Title>
          <Text style= {styles.cardElements}>Carbs</Text>
          <Progress.Bar progress={0.3} width={200} height={10} />
        </Card.Content>
        <Card.Actions>
        </Card.Actions>
      </Card>
    </View>
```

**Style-sheet:**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  bar: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
  },
  card: {
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    borderRadius: 30,
    margin: 5
  },
  cardTitle: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    fontSize: 40,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  cardElements:{
    fontSize: 20,
    paddingTop: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming there's some kind of conflict in the view so I created a separate function to contain the progress bars view. Styling it within this function allowed me to apply styles to it. For some reason anything rendered above the cards in my original code cannot be styled.

**My Solution:**

```
function MainProgress(){
  return(
    <View style = {styles.progressBar}>
      <ProgressCircle style = {styles.progressBar}
        percent={30}
        radius={100}
        borderWidth={12}
        color="#3399FF"
        shadowColor="#999"
        bgColor="#fff"
      >
      <Text>{'30%'}</Text>
      </ProgressCircle>
    </View>
  )
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component { 
  render() {  
    return (  
      <View>
        <StatusBarPlaceHolder/>
          <MainProgress/>
```